# Getting java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I am getting empty string as a result of  `invoiceItem.getDescription()`, but when i use the below code in gwt widget, i am getting
`java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:` Found interface `com.google.gwt.user.client.Element`, but class was expected

```
descTextArea.getElement().setAttribute("value", invoiceItem.getDescription());
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance
MSNaidu

Comment: Each time you are getting the same ?? as @artem said happening only while hotswap ?

Comment: yes, when i run my application in the development mode.i am wondering that it was working fine after reload the application

Answer (score 8):

Might be this quirk:
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5252

"... AFAICT, it happened when I was running dev mode and made changes to the code that Eclipse couldn't hotswap into the JVM. Refreshing the app to reload devmode fixed it.
This is annoying, but the JVM is known to not be perfect at hotswap ..."

Answer (score 0):

As @ArtemGr said it happens while hotcode replacement(*Especially Element is in the code*).

Instead of getting element and setting DOM attribute `"value"` you can simply do ,

```
TextArea area = new TextArea();
area.setValue(invoiceItem.getDescription());
```